# Not able to change launcher icon for flutter

Tags: flutter, pubspec.yaml

This is my pubsec.yaml:

```yaml
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.13.1"
flutter_launcher_icons:

  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "images/icon.png"

flutter:
  assets:
    - images/
```

This WORKED in my last project. This is the exact same thing that I did in the last project. The asset names or addresses are not wrong. I checked several times. So why does this not work this time? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you run `flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons` ? Does it read any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting up the configuration, all that is left to do is run the package.

```
flutter pub get
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons
```

Comment: > flutter pub get
yes.
> flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons
No. I did after you told me and it worked... It's strange because I don't remember doing it the last time and it still worked